# How to open second UI Datepicker on closing the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I´m trying to add some functionality to a form with JQuery UI´s Datepicker.

When a user selects the arrival date ([onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect)), a few things should happen:

1. <strike>Update the departure to 3 days after the arrival date</strike> (This works now :))
2. Split the departure date in 3 and add each part to an input field (*see arrival date example in Fiddle)*
3. When the arrival-datepicker closes ([onClose](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onClose)), the departure-datepicker should open automatically, defaulting to the date selected in point 1 (example: http://www.kayak.es )

I managed to get point 1 to work, but I´m a bit lost with the other features. If anyone can show me how to do this or get me on the right track that would be really great! I´m still a beginner but learning fast.

Here´s a Fiddle of what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/mattvic/B6Kax/13/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Split the departure date in 3 and add
>   each part to an input field**

Looks like you already have the code written for this in the `onSelect` handler of the destination datepicker. Unfortunately, it looks like `setDate` [does not trigger that event](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6264), and you cannot trigger it manually. What I would recommend is breaking that code out into a separate function that you can call from both places:

```
function splitDepartureDate(dateText) {
    var depSplit = dateText.split("-", 3);
    $('#alt-vertrek-d').val(depSplit[0]);
    $('#alt-vertrek-m').val(depSplit[1]);
    $('#alt-vertrek-y').val(depSplit[2]);
}
```

Then change your departure datepicker `onSelect` handler to point to that function:

```
$('#vertrek').datepicker({

    // Prevent selecting departure date before arrival:
    beforeShow: customRange,
    onSelect: splitDepartureDate
});
```

Lastly, call that function from your arrival's `onSelect` event handler:

```
/* snip: */

// Populate departure date field 
var nextDayDate = $('#aankomst').datepicker('getDate', '+3d');
nextDayDate.setDate(nextDayDate.getDate() + 3);
$('#vertrek').datepicker('setDate', nextDayDate);

// Manually call splitDepartureDate
splitDepartureDate($("#vertrek").val());
```

---

> **When the arrival-datepicker closes
>   (onClose), the departure-datepicker
>   should open automatically, defaulting
>   to the date selected in point 1**

This is just a matter of using the `onClose` event handler:

```
onClose: function() {
    $("#vertrek").datepicker("show");
}
```

Here's your updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/zXMke/

Comment: @Mattvic: No problem. Interesting/unfortunate that the `setDate` method doesn't trigger `onSelect`...

Comment: There is a problem with the show on close.  In the fiddle, try to select the next month range in the second calendar. Note that you need to click the month twice before it switches.  I would love to know how to fix this!

Comment: Wrapping the show call in a timeout seems to fix the next month problem. I don't exactly know why.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the title's question :

```
 $("#firsDate").datepicker('option',"onClose", function() { $( "#secondDate" ).datepicker( "show" ); });
```

Source :

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose

I recommend to use onSelect instead of onClose event in order to make sure that the 1st date has been selected before opening the second datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

point 3 answer:

```
$(function() {
  $( '#aankomst' ).datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, instance) {
      $( '#vertrek' ).datepicker('show');
     },      
    onSelect: function( dateText, instance ) {

      // Split arrival date in 3 input fields                        
      var arrSplit = dateText.split("-");
        $( '#alt-aankomst-d' ).val(arrSplit[0]);
        $( '#alt-aankomst-m' ).val(arrSplit[1]);
        $( '#alt-aankomst-y' ).val(arrSplit[2]);

       // Populate departure date field
       var nextDayDate = $( '#aankomst' ).datepicker('getDate', '+3d');
         nextDayDate.setDate( nextDayDate.getDate() + 3 );
           $( '#vertrek' ).datepicker( 'setDate', nextDayDate );
           }                
        });
});
```

you already have the solution for point 2?

Cheers,
Daddy